# Minimal representation of a slice object

Tags: python, slice, representation

Is there a builtin or easy method to represent a slice object in a way so that putting the representation inside brackets will result the relevant `__getitem__` parse the representation exactly as the original slice object? In fact, I wish to get the minimal `::` notation, and not the `slice(...)` notation (though both work).

An example will clarify: I wish to define a function `slice_repr` so that

```
slice_repr(slice(1, None))        ## Will return '1:'
slice_repr(slice(1, None, None))  ## Will return '1:'
slice_repr(slice(1, 10))          ## Will return '1:10'
slice_repr(slice(1, 10, None))    ## Will return '1:10'
slice_repr(slice(1, None, 3))     ## Will return '1::3'
slice_repr(slice(1, 10, 3))       ## Will return '1:10:3'
slice_repr(slice(10))             ## Will return ':10'
slice_repr(slice(None, 10))       ## Will return ':10'
slice_repr(slice(None, 10, 3))    ## Will return ':10:3'
slice_repr(slice(None, None, 3))  ## Will return '::3'
```

Would be even nicer if the function could handle inputs like

```
(slice(None, None, 3), Ellipsis, 3)
```

returning

```
'::3,...,3'
```

Comment: What are you going to do with such a string? You can't pass it as the argument to `__getitem__`; it will not parse such a string the required values. `__getitem__` has long supported receiving slice objects directly as an argument: `x.__getitem__(slice(10))` is equivalent to `x[:10]`.

Comment: This is for representation purposes only, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Not for an arbitrary slice, which may contain anything, such as `slice(object())`.

But if you assume the `repr` is valid, you can do:

```
def slice_slice_repr(slice_object):
    """
    Get the best guess of a minimal representation of
    a slice, as it would be created by indexexing.
    """
    slice_items = [slice_object.start, slice_object.stop, slice_object.step]

    if slice_items[-1] is None:
        slice_items.pop()

    if slice_items[-1] is None:
        return repr(slice_items[0]) + ":"

    else:
        return ":".join("" if x is None else repr(x) for x in  slice_items)

def arbitrary_slice_item_repr(object):
    """
    Get the best guess of a minimal representation of
    an item from an iterable recieved by __getitem__.
    """
    if type(object) is slice:
        return slice_slice_repr(object)

    elif object is Ellipsis:
        return "..."

    else:
        return repr(object)

def slice_repr(object):
    """
    Get the best guess of a minimal representation of
    an object recieved by __getitem__.
    """
    # Yes, "type(X) is Y" *is* the correct thing to do
    if type(object) is slice:
        return slice_slice_repr(object)

    if type(object) is tuple:
        return ",".join(map(arbitrary_slice_item_repr, object))

    else:
        return arbitrary_slice_item_repr(object)

slice_repr(slice(1, None))        ## Will return '1:'
slice_repr(slice(1, None, None))  ## Will return '1:'
slice_repr(slice(1, 10))          ## Will return '1:10'
slice_repr(slice(1, 10, None))    ## Will return '1:10'
slice_repr(slice(1, None, 3))     ## Will return '1::3'
slice_repr(slice(1, 10, 3))       ## Will return '1:10:3'
slice_repr(slice(10))             ## Will return ':10'
slice_repr(slice(None, 10))       ## Will return ':10'
slice_repr(slice(None, 10, 3))    ## Will return ':10:3'
slice_repr(slice(None, None, 3))  ## Will return '::3'
#>>> '1:'
#>>> '1:'
#>>> '1:10'
#>>> '1:10'
#>>> '1::3'
#>>> '1:10:3'
#>>> ':10'
#>>> ':10'
#>>> ':10:3'
#>>> '::3'

slice_repr((slice(None, None, 3), Ellipsis, 3))
#>>> '::3,...,3'
```

There are a lot of special cases, and this definitely isn't solid. It is, however, approximately right.

This also doesn't deal with cases like `X[[...]]` on Python 3. Those are very difficult to get right, because any container using `repr` will be "wrong". You have to special-case for every object you expect might contain an `Ellipsis`, which is a pain.

The same problem doesn't hold for `slice` because it can only appear at the top-level of a `__getitem__`, so `X[[1:2]]` cannot happen. On Python 2, `...` also seems to have this restriction.

Comment: Thanks! Isn't X[[...]] syntax error? (it is at least on 2.7, I guess)

Comment: Strange; Python 3 has `...` as proper syntax usable *anywhere*. Please note I've updated my code a few times, the original answer was wrong.

Comment: _"Yes, `type(X) is Y` *is* the correct thing to do"_ - why? What if I subclass tuple or slice?

Comment: @Eric A slice subclass cannot be created with slice syntax, so should not have a `repr` that resolves to it.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't do the nicer functions, but this snippet this seems to do all of your examples finely.

```
a = str(slice(1, 10)).replace('None, None','None').replace('slice(','').replace(', ',':').replace(')','').replace('None','')
if a.count(':') > 1 and a[len(a)-1] == ':': #Needed for cases like 1, 10, None
    a = a[:-1]
```